# What's the best strategy for implementing cut and paste in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, copy-paste, nspasteboard

Implementing copy and paste is very straightforward with `NSPasteBoard`. However, `NSPasteBoard` doesn't seem to provide an obvious method to implement cut and paste. One strategy is to first copy then delete, but that only works for simply types such as strings or text but becomes ineffective when manipulating files. What's the best way to implement cut and paste in Cocoa?

Comment: Unlike Windows, the Mac has never had cut and paste for files. Only in Lion has the ability to move (rather than copy) files in the Finder been added, using Copy then Option-Paste. Still no Cut.

Comment: Ok, so I suppose NSPasteBoard was never really designed to support cut and paste then? If so, what would be a practical strategy for implementing this in a custom application?